# Angular Protractor how to get all the td in a tr using findElements(by.tagName)

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor

I am new to Angular + Protractor automated testing. I am trying to loop through the rows of a html table and want to get each column value of that row. using the below code but not working.

```
$$('#mat-tab-content-0-2 > div > app-pick-loss-method > div.data-table-container.table > table > tbody').$$('tr').each(function (el, index) {
  if (index > 0) {
    el.findElements(by.tagName('td')).then(function (cols) {
      console.log('Subline: ', cols[0].getText());
      console.log('Cat Indicator: ', cols[1].getText());
      console.log('Method: ', cols[2].getText());
      console.log('ELC: ', cols[3].getText());
      console.log('Selected CV: ', cols[4].getText());
      console.log('Weight: ', cols[5].getText());
    });
  }
})
```

Can anyone help what is the right way to do this without errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all  HTML tags, I don't think you could find it through tagName(). Try something like this:

```html
el = element.all(by.css('#mat-tab-content-0-2 td'));
  el.getText().then((text) => {
    for (let i=0; i < text.lenght; i++){
      console.log(text[i]);
    }
})
```

You will get text from all  (if css selector is OK)

Answer (score 0):

Would be helpful if you include what error you are getting with your code, but anyway, try changing the following line:

`.findElements` > `.all` :

`el.findElements(by.tagName('td')).then(function (cols) {`
should be:
`el.all(by.tagName('td')).then(function (cols) {`

Answer (score 0):

Just stop using `.then()` syntax, use `async/await` and everything will be straightforward. Something like this

```
let tableRows = $$('#mat-tab-content-0-2 > div > app-pick-loss-method > div.data-table-container.table > table > tbody tr');
let rowCount = await tableRows.count();

for (let i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
  let cells = tableRows.get(i).all(by.css("td"));
  let cellCount = await cells.count();

  for (let j = 0; j < cellCount; j++) {
    console.log('Cell ' + j + " " + await cells.get(j).getText())
  }
}
```

Comment: error in line  tableRows.get(i).element.all(by.css("td")); all does not exist on type ElementFinder